# Want to perform > and < operations with column, but need SQL to read as a date

Tags: sql, date, casting

trying to figure out how to get SQL to read a value as a date.

I have a db that has columns like this:

```
id  created_at
1   2010-12-16
2   2010-12-16
3   2010-12-17
4   2010-12-21
5   2010-12-23
6   2011-01-04
```

I did not create the table using SQL; it was generated as text and imported to an SQL server. I'm not sure how to write my query so that it knows that created_at is a date, so I can use clauses like "WHERE created_at <'2010-10-17', etc, like I can do from a normal SQL db. Is Cast the route to go here? As in SELECT Cast(created_at as ...something?) haven't been able to find anything useful elsewhere.

Comment: You may be better off inserting the data from that table into a new table that has `created_at` as a DateTime

Comment: Perhaps I'm missing something, but string comparison will work fine with this date format.  This is one of the big advantages of YYYY-MM-DD or YYYYMMDD as a date format.  In other words, your proposed WHERE clause will work as is.  Now, if you want to find the day of the week, or do date arithmetic, then you'll want to convert the value to a date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if using SQL Server you can cast the column as a date as you've guessed:

```
select cast(created_at as date) 
from myTable

select * 
from myTable 
where cast(created_at as date) >= '2012-01-01'
```

However you'd need to do that each time you queried the table which is pretty inefficient.  Better would be to redefine the table to make that column a date type by default.  If you can post your table's DDL statement (sql to create the table) up here I can write your conversion code for you.  Alternatively, use the code below to alter the table after creation:

```
alter table myTable 
alter column created_at date
```

Cheers,

JB

Edit based on comments.  If you're unable to change the datatype and it's an ntext column, first use substring to convert to an nvarchar, then use the cast function:

```
select * 
from myTable 
where cast(substring(created_at,1,10) as date) >= '2012-01-01'
```

Comment: ps. since you've used the international date format (i.e. yyyy-mm-dd) you can still use the greater than / less than operators successfully, since in this format a string comparison is identical in function to a date comparison - and if keeping the column as a string (char/nchar/varchar/nvarchar) is a requirement, this saves the overhead of first converting all values to dates before comparing them.

Comment: Citations for pst ;)                                                   alter table alter column: [link](http://sqlserverplanet.com/sql/alter-table-alter-column)                                                          cast: [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx)

Comment: Much appreciated, but the site I'm using doesn't work for creating tables as far as I know, just for querying  http://skyserver.sdss3.org/casjobs/default.aspx , and I don't use sql enough to have a quick way to do so. My current with this task is not long-term so I'm not worried about performance, just need to get the job done, so I'm hoping I can find a way to query this that will work! Using cast(created_at as date) or datetime gives me this error, though: Explicit conversion from data type ntext to datetime is not allowed

Comment: StingyJack - no idea; I'm just providing references to documentation for more info as a pre-emptive placater.  What you put looks good to me.

Comment: Mel - ahh - ntext allows for huge amounts of text, so is harder to convert.  Since you know the date will always be 10 chars though you can use substring to convert to nvarchar, then use the cast on that:  select * from myTable where cast(substring(created_at,1,10) as date) > '2012-01-01'

Comment: Yes! JohnB- that did the trick. Thank you so much! Also everyone else that contributed.

Comment: @mel for the future, ntext is deprecated, you should not be using that datatype. If an automated tooll is doing this, you should let the company know that there is an issue that will need to be solved.

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT CAST (created_at as DATETIME)
```

...should give you the value you want. However the performance is going to be bad if you are casting those as part of a WHERE clause. You may want to add another date specific column to the table like "created_at_date" and wire your queries to it.

If this is not working and throwing a casting error, its likely because one or more of the values in the column is not consistent with the format you displayed above. It could be NULL or blank or just garbage format. Your best bet is to add the column like JohnLBevan and I have both suggested and convert as much over as you can. Then you can query for the items that did not convert.

Also, have you looked into generating a number table or dates table?